# python regex result and Regetron result differ

Tags: python, regex

I have installed [regetron](https://gitorious.org/regetron) and issued following :

```
>> !data "aaaaaaaaaaaaaab"
> a{3,5}
0000: aaaaaaaaaaaaaab
```

should not it match the **aaaaa** 5 a characters (Expected) ?

In python , it is coming as expected

```
>>> m=re.search('a{3,5}', "aaaaaaaaaaaaaab")
>>> m.group(0)
'aaaaa'
```

In regetron, why output not coming as expected ?

Comment: Do you have match mode enabled in regetron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [regetron README](https://gitorious.org/regetron/regetron/source/d3a8fc9d32e31e2167c87eff73908bce44823468%3aREADME#L62):

> Type your regex at the prompt and hit enter. It'll show you **the lines** that match that regex, or nothing if nothing matches.

If your regular expression contains group(s), it will show you result of `re.findall`:

```
> (a{3,5})
0000: ['aaaaa', 'aaaaa', 'aaaa']
> (aaa)(...)
0000: [('aaa', 'aaa'), ('aaa', 'aaa')]
```